# how to apply a function to all sublists recursively in common lisp?

Tags: list, loops, recursion, lisp, common-lisp

now I have a list:

```
(+ x (- 4 9))
```

I first need (- 4 9) change to (- (4 . 0) (9 . 0))
(please do worry this part too much)

```
(defun typecheck (A)
(cond
  ((numberp A)
   (cons A 0))
  ((equal A 'x)
   (cons 1 1))
  (t A)))
```

then I need to subtract (4 . 0) and (9 . 0) (still this is not my problem, I don't want to post this function because it is too long...

so it becomes

```
(+ x (-5 . 0))
```

now this time I change x to (1 . 1) so the list becomes (+ (1 . 1) (- 5 . 0))
I finally add them together (final result is (-4 . 1))

My main problem is how to let Lisp know I want to calculate them first after I got (- (4 . 0) (9 .0)) ? My function will just go stright to (+ (1 . 1) ((- 4 .0) (9 . 0)) and gave me an error msg.

My process :

```
(defun check (A)
  (cond
   ((atom A)
    (let ((newA (typecheck A)))
      (calucalte A)))
   ((listp A)
    (mapcar #'check A))
```

but this function won't store anything...and I have no idea how to do it :( can anyone give me some help? THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the problem correctly you should just write a single recursive function handling operations and number/symbol conversion, for example:

```
(defun tcheck (expr)
  (cond
    ((numberp expr)
     (cons expr 0))
    ((eq expr 'x)
     (cons 1 1))
    ((listp expr)
     (cond
       ((eq (first expr) '+)
        (let ((a (tcheck (second expr)))
              (b (tcheck (third expr))))
          (cons (+ (car a) (car b))
                (+ (cdr a) (cdr b)))))
       ((eq (first expr) '-)
        (let ((a (tcheck (second expr)))
              (b (tcheck (third expr))))
          (cons (- (car a) (car b))
                (- (cdr a) (cdr b)))))
       (T
         (error "Unknown operation"))))
    (T expr)))
```

With the above function

```
(tcheck '(+ x (- 4 9)))
```

returns `(-4 . 1)`

Comment: Oh, thanks! that work perfect for my function :DDD (I changed the cons part because I have specifc functions for that)